# Python auth using requests

Tags: python, http, authentication, python-requests

I am trying to implement a custom ApiClient in Python, using requests.
The way it does authentication is by:

1. login(username, password) -> get back a token if valid, http error code if not
2. set the token in `{'Authorization': token}` header and use that header for all endpoints which need authentication

Can you check if the code looks OK, and if not what kind of changes would you recommend?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
import json
import os
import sys


def read_file_contents(path):
    if os.path.exists(path):
        with open(path) as infile:
            return infile.read().strip()


class ApiClient():
    token = None
    api_url = 'http://10.0.1.194:1234'
    session = requests.Session()

    def __init__(self):
        self.token = self.load_token()

        if self.token:
            self.session.headers.update({'Authorization': self.token})
        else:
            # if no token, do login
            if not self.token:
                try:
                    self.login()
                except requests.HTTPError:
                    sys.exit('Username-password invalid')

    def load_token(self):
        return read_file_contents('token')

    def save_token(self, str):
        with open('token', 'w') as outfile:
            outfile.write(str)

    def login(self):
        email = '1@1.hu'
        password = 'passwd'

        headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
        payload = {
            'email': email,
            'password': password
        }
        r = requests.post(self.api_url + '/auth',
                          data=json.dumps(payload),
                          headers=headers)

        # raise exception if cannot login
        r.raise_for_status()

        # save token and update session
        self.token = r.json()['session']['token']
        self.save_token(self.token)
        self.session.headers.update({'Authorization': self.token})

    def test_auth(self):
        r = self.session.get(self.api_url + '/auth/is-authenticated')
        return r.ok


if __name__ == '__main__':
    api = ApiClient()
    print api.test_auth()
```

Comment: the email-password will obviously not be hard coded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have time to do a thorough review, but here are some comments based on a casual reading.

- In `read_file_contents`, the function returns `None` if the file doesn’t exist. I’d suggest modifying this to print or return an explicit message to that effect, to make debugging easier later. For example, something like:

  ```
  def read_file_contents(path):
      try:
          with open(path) as infile:
              return infile.read().strip()
      except FileNotFoundError:
          print "Couldn't find the token file!"
          return None
  ```

  will make your life easier later.

  Also, is this meant to be `open(path, 'r')`?
- New-style classes should inherit from object: that is, use

  ```
  class ApiClient(object):
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  class ApiClient():
  ```
- Don't copy and paste the API URL throughout your code. Make it a variable, and then pass `api_url` as an input to `ApiClient()`. That way, you can reuse this code for other APIs, or make changes to the URL in a single place. (If, for example, the API changes.)
- **Don't hard code username, email and password in the `login` function.** It makes it harder to change them later, and it's a security risk. Consider using something like the [`keyring`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring) module for storing sensitive information. (Should the token be stored securely as well?)
- The `__init__` function uses the token, and also retrieves it from the file. This can cause problems if you later get the token from somewhere else. (For example, if you used `keyring`.) Instead, consider passing `token` as an argument to `__init__`, and having the code to obtain the token somewhere else. Something like:

  ```
  def __init__(self, api_url, token=None):
      self.api_url = api_url
      self.token = token

      if self.token is not None:
          # if you get a token
      else:
          # if you don't
  ```

  and then later:

  ```
  if __name__ == '__main__':
      api_token = read_file_contents('token')
      api_url = 'http://10.0.1.194:1234'
      api = ApiClient(api_token, api_url)
      print api.test_auth()
  ```

Comment: Even better than returning `None` if the file is unreadable, just let the exception propagate, and catch it in `__init__()`.

Comment: `open()` mode is `'r'` by default.

Comment: @200_success While that is true, it could be argued that this qualifies as "explicit is better than implicit".